# Verify there is no file references between solution projects

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, solution

Assume there are two projects in .NET solution:

```
Solution
    - Project1
    - Project2
```

I want to have only `Project References` from Project2 to Project1 like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="Project1.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But sometimes developers add wrong `File References` instead like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Project1">
    <HintPath>path\to\Project1.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I be sure there are no `File References` between solution projects? Ideally it should be a build error, but what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: Maybe you can use tooling to help with this, such as NsDepCop: https://github.com/realvizu/NsDepCop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's possible to add `MSBuild` task (target) that checks all solution projects for the file references. This task must be added to all projects or to `Directory.Build.targets`. This is the target:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Analyzing '$(MSBuildProjectFile)' for file references between solution projects...&#xA;" />

    <GetSolutionProjects Solution="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\YourSolutionName.sln">
      <Output ItemName="Projects" TaskParameter="Output"/>
    </GetSolutionProjects>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <Expression>(@(Projects->'%(ProjectName)', '|')).dll</Expression>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <XmlRead XmlFileName="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" XPath="//Project/ItemGroup/Reference/HintPath">
      <Output ItemName="FileReferences" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </XmlRead>

    <RegexMatch Input="@(FileReferences)" Expression="$(Expression)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Output" ItemName ="ProjectReferences" />
    </RegexMatch>

    <Error Text="There must be no file references between solution projects, but it was found in '$(MSBuildProjectFile)' to the following file(s): %(ProjectReferences.Identity)"
           Condition="'%(ProjectReferences.Identity)' != ''" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This target uses [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) therefore don't forget to add this NuGet package to all you projects (or to `Directory.Build.props`).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple PowerShell

```
$path = "D:\temp\Solution1"
$extension = "csproj"


#-------------------

$projects = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter "*.$($extension)"

$projectsList = @()

# Create the project's solution list
foreach ($project in $projects)
{
    $projectsList += $project
}


foreach($project in $projectsList)
{   
    # Read the project xml
    [xml]$proj = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($project.FullName)

    # loop throught ItemGroup
    foreach($item in $proj.Project.ItemGroup)
    {

        # Looking for project reference
        $all = $projectsList | where {$_.Name -eq "$($item.Reference.Include).$($extension)"} 

        foreach($ref in $all)
        {
            Write-Warning "Find wrong reference for $($ref.Name) on $($project.Name)"
        }
    }

}
```